# unchecking apply selection as a filter in microstrategy gives no data

Tags: microstrategy

I have an attribute selector and I wish to use USE FIRST option on it. So I uncheck the apply selection as a filter. But doing so, makes my selector empty. It does not show any data. And when I use apply selection as a filter, it shows the data.
Does any one have any idea, why it might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply selection as a filter, the request is sent to the iServer and then the browser receives it. However when we dont select that check box, the selector request is not sent to iServer. It is more of the operation happening at the browser level. I am not sure why you are not seeing data at all.